# RVM wrapper not generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to generate a gem wrapper in ubuntu terminal command window.
following this [link](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/06/create-run-and-manage-your-background-processes-with-upstart/)
I generate use default global gemset.

```
rvm alias create test_app ruby-1.9.3-p448
```

After generate it says:

```
Creating alias for test_app for ruby-1.9.3-p448.
Recording alias for test_app for ruby-1.9.3-p448.
```

But when I change dir to check my wrapper generated.
There's nothing under my /usr/local/rvm/wrappers directory.

```
cd /usr/local/rvm/wrappers 

ls
```

nothig is there under wrappers folder.is all empty

why is that?thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the rvm path you folow may not be the same as ur path.
use echo $rvm_path to get ur rvm path.

https://rvm.io/integration/init-d